# How to make a formal proof with A → (B ∨ C) ⊢ (A → B) ∨ (A → C)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

[Here is what I've got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiPcs.png)

I feel like I need an indirect proof for this and so I need to prove a contradiction with one of line 4 or 5. I'm not sure how to approach it. Any hints that can help me in the right direction please

Comment: But a proof by contra is not the only way... You can simply assume $A$ and then use Disjunction Elim on $(B \lor C)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

**You have a premise.  Make use of it.**

Assume $\lnot((A\to B)\vee(A\to C))$.   Assume $A$.   Eliminate the premises' conditional, to derive $B\vee C$.   Eliminate that disjunction to derive $B$.   Discharge the assumption of $A$ to introduce a conditional, and thereafter complete the reduction to absurdity proof.

$$\fitch{A\to B\vee C}{\fitch{\lnot((A\to B)\vee(A\to C))}{\fitch{A}{B\vee C\\{\fitch{B}{~}\\\fitch{C}{\fitch{~}{~}\\~\vdots\\B}}\\B}\\A\to B\\\phantom{(A\to B)\vee (A\to C)}\\\bot}\\\lnot\lnot((A\to B)\vee (A\to C))\\(A\to B)\vee (A\to C)}$$

Comment: So to discharge the disjunction of BvC, either I would need ~C to prove B or I would need to make two subproofs. I think the two subproofs is the way to go but I run into the problem where I don't know how to prove B from an assumption of C. Obviously, I can prove B with an assumption of B. Any hints on that part? Thanks

Comment: Yes! @bprime  A proof by cases is the way to go.  **Hint:** $B$ may be derived by *ex falso quodlibet* (explosion!) *if* you can derive a contradiction (and you can).